# dropping the tables in sqlite in ROR for ubuntu environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have doing some POC in Ruby-on-Rails and using sqlite database, while doing this I have different versions of db migration files.I want to drop all the tables in sqlite db to start afresh, there are ways of doing migration using versions but I want some handle for the sqlite (irrespective of ROR framework).
do I have to install some gem to access sqlite db? or is there any straight forward way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to reset your tables to an empty state, then you can use

```
rake db:reset
```

This will drop the database and run your migrations again. If what you want is to drop the database completely, then run

```
rake db:drop
```

Comment: Also ```db:reset``` will seed your db with ```seeds.rb```

Answer (score 1):

You can also drop table from rails console

Example:

```
 ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:table_name)
```